# Function owned() is public

Tags: erc-20

Since function owned is public, does it mean anyone can externally call it and own the contract as msg.sender?

```
contract owned {
    address public owner;

    function owned() public {
        owner = msg.sender;
    }

    modifier onlyOwner {
        require(msg.sender == owner);
        _;
    }

    function transferOwnership(address newOwner) onlyOwner public {
        owner = newOwner;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this particular case, no. The contract is also called `owned`, so the function acts as the constructor.

In recent versions of solidity, you should explicitly declare it as `constructor() public {..}` to avoid confusion, and to prevent bugs in scenarios such as renaming the contract and forgetting to change the function name.

If the function and contract had different names, then yes, it would be public and invokable by anyone

Answer (score 1):

This is a constructor in Solidity versions prior 0.4.21, so it has to be `public`, and it cannot be called on an existing contract (can only be called in order to deploy a new contract).

As of Solidity v0.4.21 onward, you can replace `function owned` with `constructor`.

This syntax extension has been applied in order to reduce the potential of someone renaming the constructor without renaming the contract, thus exposing it as a regular public function.

Comment: "However, from Solidity v0.4.21 onward, you'll need to replace function owned with constructor, otherwise this function will indeed pose a security breach." This is untrue. The old syntax for a constructor is deprecated, but using it poses no security risk.

Comment: @smarx: The old syntax makes the constructor a public function, callable by anyone. Is that wrong?

Comment: Yes, that's wrong. The old syntax works the same way it always did.

Comment: @smarx: So the only security issue is the potential of someone renaming the constructor (which is plausible when the old syntax is used, but not likely to happen when the new syntax is used), thus exposing it as a regular public function?

Comment: Yes. That's why using the new constructor syntax is preferred.

Comment: @smarx: Thank you for the enlightenment, I will update.